# Need assistance with Vigenere Cipher program

Tags: c++

I am helping a friend create a program that encrypts/decrypts messages using the "Vigenere Cipher." I was unsure what this was, so I did my own research and think I have it figured out.

My code runs fine from a syntax perspective. But, from a logic perspective, it does not work. From my understanding, when I encrypt a message with a key, if I decrypt the encrypted message using the same key, it should give me the original message. Mine does not. From my debugging attempts, I think the issue lies somewhere in my decrypting algorithm, but could be entirely wrong.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


int main(){

    //initializing functions to be used
    int giveInfo();
    void encrypt(string message, string key);
    void decrypt(string message, string key);
    void newKey(string key);
    string keyInput();
    string messageInput();
    int userChoice();

    giveInfo();

    //loop so that the user can decrypt/encrypt multiple messages
    int counter = 1;
    int userCounter;

    while (counter == 1){
    int choice = userChoice();

    if(choice == 1){
    string inputMessage = messageInput();
    string inputKey = keyInput();

    encrypt(inputMessage, inputKey);
    }

    else{
    string inputMessage = messageInput();
    string inputKey = keyInput();

    decrypt(inputMessage, inputKey);
    }

    cout << "Would you like to decrypt/encrypt another message? (1 = yes, 2 = no)";
    cin >> userCounter;

    counter = userCounter;

    system("CLS");
}

    return 0;
}



//gives the user a basic description of cypher and what they need to input

int giveInfo(){
    cout << "\nThe Vigenere Cypher is a polyalphabetic encryption/decryption method. It utilizes a 'key' (provided by the user, \nany word of any length) to determine which letters will replace others. This means in order to decrypt a message,\n one will need the key the person who encrypted the messafe used, ensuring a secure encryption. To use this program, \nyou will need to enter your message (this will be converted into all capitol letters) and a key which you would like to use. Do not use any spaces in your message.\n\n\n";
    return 0;
}



string messageInput(){
    //message place holder
    string userMessage;

    //asking for message
    cout << "What is the message you would like to encrypt/decrypt?\n";
    cin >> userMessage;

    return userMessage;
}



string keyInput(){
    //key place holder
    string userKey;

    //asking for key
    cout << "What is the key you would like to use?\n";
    cin >> userKey; 

    return userKey;
}



void decrypt(string message, string key){

    //generating new key to match message length
    int x = message.size();

    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        if (x == i)
            i = 0;
        if (key.size() == message.size())
            break;
        key.push_back(key[i]);
    }

   string orig_text;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < message.size(); i++)
    {
        // converting in range 0-25
        int x = (message[i] - key[i] + 26) %26;

        // convert into alphabets(ASCII)
        x += 'A';
        orig_text.push_back(x);
    }

    cout << "\n\nEncrypted Code: " + message+ "\n";
    cout << "Key: " + key+ "\n";
    cout << "Decrypted message: ";
    cout << orig_text + "\n";
}



//takes user input (message to be encyrpted and key to be used) as arguments and returns encrypted 
void encrypt(string message, string key){

    string cipher_text;

    //generating new key to match message length
    int x = message.size();

    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        if (x == i)
            i = 0;
        if (key.size() == message.size())
            break;
        key.push_back(key[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < message.size(); i++)
    {
        // converting in range 0-25
        int x = (message[i] + key[i]) %26;

        // convert into alphabets(ASCII)
        x += 'A';

        cipher_text.push_back(x);
    }

    cout << "\n\nOriginal message: " + message+ "\n";
    cout << "Key: " + key+ "\n";
    cout << "Encrypted message: ";
    cout << cipher_text + "\n";
}



int userChoice(){
    int choice;

    cout << "Would you like to encrypt a message or decrypt a message? (1 = 
    encrypt, 2 = decrypt)\n";
    cin >> choice;

    return choice;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your intention is to use an alphabet with a length of 26, you need to make sure your input is properly normalized prior to performing any encryption/decryption operations.

I would suggest ensuring that user input for the message & key is converted to upper case.
e.g. utilizing [toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/): `for(char &c : inputMessage) c = toupper(c)`

Could you provide your input & output?  Your code works just fine.

```
Original Message: ATTACKATDAWN
Key: LEMONLEMONLE
Encrypted Message: LXFOPVEFRNHR

Encrypted Code: LXFOPVEFRNHR
Key: LEMONLEMONLE
Decrypted Message: ATTACKATDAWN
```

Comment: I completely forgot to convert the key and the message to uppercase. Sometimes when you're tired you try so hard to figure out what the issue is, you don't realize it's something as simple as that. Thank you!